# How to add API key to the IBM Bluemix Node-RED web service

Tags: web-services, ibm-cloud, api-key, node-red

I have created a simple web service in IBM Bluemix using the "http request" node of Node-RED and I was trying to implement some security by add the API key to this but I couldn't find any node or setting to enable the API key.
Just wanted to check is it possible to enable the API key for this service in Bluemix.

I call this web service from a mobile client app using AJAX 
http://mySample.w3ibm.mybluemix.net/testsignup?email=myemailid@domain.com

Node Flow is as below...

[{"id":"875af59a.611b3","type":"http response","z":"87dcd3a7.509eb","name":"response to client","x":672,"y":210,"wires":[]},{"id":"a0cf9959.a493e","type":"http in","z":"87dcd3a7.509eb","name":"testsignup","url":"/testsignup","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":137,"y":114,"wires":[["dc601c04.700e38"]]},{"id":"dc601c04.700e38","type":"function","z":"87dcd3a7.509eb","name":"create password","func":"\nvar randomstring = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);\nvar credentials = {\"user\": msg.req.query.email, \"password\": randomstring};\n    \n/*msg.to = msg.req.query.email; msg.topic = \"Your Password for RBS account\"\nmsg.description = \"Use these credentials to Login\";*/\n\nmsg.payload = credentials;\nmsg.statusCode = 200;\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":341,"y":116,"wires":[["d269e91a.349cc8","875af59a.611b3"]]},{"id":"d269e91a.349cc8","type":"debug","z":"87dcd3a7.509eb","name":"search result","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":678,"y":115,"wires":[]}]

Comment: Do you mean the http-request node (calling out to a remote service) or hte http-in & http-out node to host a service in Node-RED?

Comment: I have updated the question with node flow & how I make use of the service

Answer (score 1):

If you use the *ibmiot* input node, in the node settings you can enable API Key authentication.

Before you can use the API you will need:

1. The identifier of your IoT Foundation organization. This is a short character string (for example "fxjlma") which you can find by logging into the IBM IoT Foundation Dashboard at https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/dashboard.
2. An API Key for your application. You can create an API Key by logging into the IBM IoT Foundation Dashboard and clicking on the API Keys Link. If you have more than one application using the API, we suggest you create distinct API Keys for each application.
3. The Auth Token that was issued when you created your API Key.

Please refer to the [IBM IoT Foundation Docs](https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/api-documentation/) for further information (IoTF boilerplate is based on Node-RED just like Node-RED boilerplate, but the former provides an example flow when you create your application).

Comment: Umberto, I am not sure the ibmiot input node serves my purpose. I have updated the question with more details. I am making use of this web service in a mobile client app as a signup request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at adding this node, it works in conjunction with a http input node:

http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-httpauth

Comment: This is something new to me, I am exploring this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard Function node to modify the msg headers, payload, etc.
Then, wire this to your HTTP Request node.